# how to generate template by underscore.js with two _.each

Tags: jquery, underscore.js, each

hello~~

I have datas like this:

```
var datas = [
  {
     country:'USA',
     citys:[
        { 
          name:'New York'
        } ,
        { 
          name:'Hawaii'
        } 
     ]
  },
  {
     country:'China',
     citys:[
        { 
          name:'Shangahai'
        } ,
        { 
          name:'Beijing'
        } 
     ]
  }

]
```

And i need to use underscore template method to grenerate the template result like this

```
<h3>USA</h3>
<ul>
  <li>New York</li>
  <li>Hawaii</li>
</ul>
<h3>China</h3>
<ul>
  <li>Shanghai</li>
  <li>Beijing</li>
</ul>
```

i use template bellow , but it didn't work!

```
 <% _.each(datas, function(district) { %>
           <h3><%= district.districtName %></h3>
           <ul>
              _.each(district.citys,function(city){
                 <li><%= city.name %></li>
              }
          </ul>

    <% }); %>
```

would and help to tell me how to deal with it? or is there any other solution to fix it?
thank you!

Comment: In addition to the formatting errors noted in the answers, your outer loop is printing ``district.districtName`` but the property  on the object in your code is ``country``.

Answer (score 0):

You need to have this code in your `render` view function. And your template has error. Below is fixed template.

Template:

```
<% _.each(datas, function(district) { %>
     <h3><%= district.districtName %></h3>
     <ul>
         <% _.each(district.citys,function(city){ %>
             <li><%= city.name %></li>
         <% }); %>
     </ul>
<% }); %>
```

Code:

```
 var datas = [
      {
         country:'USA',
         citys:[
            { 
              name:'New York'
            } ,
            { 
              name:'Hawaii'
            } 
         ]
      },
      {
         country:'China',
         citys:[
            { 
              name:'Shangahai'
            } ,
            { 
              name:'Beijing'
            } 
         ]
      }
    ];

    var templateStr = '<div></div>'; // load template from server
    var template = _.template(templateStr);
    var generatedHtml = template({ datas : datas });
```

Your need to have set data to template generator like this. So you can use `datas` variable in you underscore template.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to passing the parameter of datas as maketest noted, the inner loop in your template is not enclosed in <% %> and is missing a closing semicolon.

```
<% _.each(datas, function(district) { %>
           <h3><%= district.districtName %></h3>
           <ul>
             <% _.each(district.citys,function(city){ %>
                 <li><%= city.name %></li>
              <% }); %>
          </ul>

    <% }); %>
```